# logmein under ubuntu to manage windows server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have to manage some windows server by logmein. But I use ubuntu as client... looks that logmein does not work under linux... it's the same for you ?
Simply I connect to logmein, I authenticate myself, try to connect.. java giveme some errors..

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed on the Linux side?  Have you checked the Logmein support with regard to your problem?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_51"
I asked in the logmein forum but without answer for now..

Answer (score 2):

Logmein Hamachi is indeed available for **Linux** distribution & a installation process itself archived under **[Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Hamachi)**'s official wiki page. The only problem is that it supports only command line version. But now with **Haguichi** its possible using GUI. Follow this to install Hamachi & Haguichi (if GUI is your preference).

- Firstly, fire-up a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) & type;

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'd suggest to update the system. And on a related note, refer below before installing;

*Make sure you have the LSB 3.0 (or above) package installed prior to attempt installing the product. If you had an older version of Hamachi for Linux, please make sure you uninstall it prior to attempt installing the latest software and read the README file located in the download package. Make sure that you have an ARMv4T or better processor and tun/tap driver installed before running Hamachi for Linux with ARM support.*

- Then, visit [**Logmein Labs**](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/labs/?iislang=en-US&lang=en#HamachiforLinux) & download your preferred package & open it with Ubuntu software center or you may use `dpkg` via terminal. If you're using `dpkg`, then navigate to the location where you've downloaded the file with `cd` command & issue below;

```
 sudo dpkg -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.119-1_i386.deb        # this is an example
```

- Once installed, you may use command line to operate (as I've mentioned earlier, its a command line interface).

```
hamachi --help             # this is manual for hamachi, refer accordingly
```

Else refer below on installing **Haguichi** for GUI which integrates well with Hamachi.

- Add PPA to the Ubuntu repo & update while installing haguichi. Type below commands;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/haguichi
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install haguichi
```

- Agree to any prompts. Haguichi will be installed and appear in your desktop menu under Internet or Applications, depending on what UI you use.

You may refer my video on **[How to install LogMeIn Hamachi on Linux](http://www.geeklk.com/2011/07/how-to-install-logmein-hamachi-in-linux-video/)** for more clear understanding. Also refer the sources below for further understanding.

**Source:** [How to Install and Use Hamachi on Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.thecoderanger.com/how-to-install-and-use-hamachi-on-ubuntu-10-10/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok I installed and it look works, but now How can I connect to the windows server ?

Comment: We should also make known that Hamachi is ***NOT*** the same as LogMeIn Remote

Answer (score 0):

9 years later....   I wanted to post so this is documented somewhere and searchable.   The only thing I found that will work is to apt-install wine from default Ubuntu repos.
Then download and install MyPal browser based of PaleMoon (https://www.mypal-browser.org/).  Run MyPal browser via wine launcher and login to LogMeIn, connect to the computer and click "remote control" or "File transfer" so it downloads the LogMeIn_Client.exe.  Run that program via wine program launcher and it will work.  Works great btw.

Comment: Mypal is still unstable by their developers' own admission. This represents a potential security vulnerability.